# How to create folder and store file in user mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile

I am using Visual studio 2019 with C#. In my website i have given option to user to download the data in pdf format. But i do not know how to create a folder in mobile and automatically download the pdf file in that folder. I have done the following coding to create pdf. I am using iText7 to create pdf.

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("c:\\Appointments.pdf);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4); 
            Paragraph header = new Paragraph("Patent Record");
            document.Add(header);
            Paragraph subheader = new Paragraph("Appointment List");  
            document.Add(subheader);
            document.Close();
}
```

Comment: If a user goes to your website to download a file, your website wouldn't have access to dow anything... besides serving the file

Comment: on web programming this is not valid - what you try there is works for desktop programming -